# What does it exactly mean to say "In XXX, we have YYY"?

Tags: meaning

> In XXX(country name) we have very affordable colleges.

Does it mean "Colleges in XXX are very affordable" or "In XXX, there are some colleges that are very affordable"?

Comment: Either works...

Comment: None of *all*, *some*, or *every* are used in the original sentence, so any interpretation of that is a possibly false assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only meaning that can be assumed from that sentence is that there are a number of very affordable colleges in the country. There could be two of them and this sentence would still be true.

It doesn't mean that all colleges in the country are very affordable. Depending on the context, the vagueness that causes your confusion could even be a deliberate way of drawing attention away from the fact that some colleges in the country are not very affordable.

As stated in the comments, both of your two interpretations are valid.